# Validate email python library runs really slow on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, email-validation

We would like to use the following python library to validate email addresses by smtp check: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email

The strange thing is that from locally it responds in 1 sec, but if we deploy it to an AWS ec2 instance, the response time jumps up to 5-6 sec. We already asked the support to remove the email sending limit and open the ports for us.

Does anyone have any idea why is it this slow?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the email server you are trying to validate located, and where is the ec2 instance located ?

Comment: The email servers are general email servers, but even if I try Hungarian ones it is slow. Our ec2 is located in the Ireland region.